# Vectorization Of Circle Mapping

Tags: algorithm, matlab, vectorization, precision

I am trying to vectorize the following formula for big n:

**x(n+1)= (x(n) + a) mod 1**

Where a is an **irrational number** on [0,1].

It can be shown that

x(n+1) = (x(1) + (n-1)*a) mod 1.

A straightforward code would look like

```
x = mod (x(1)+(1:n-1)*a,1);
```

This, however, will produce **loss of precision** for **big n**.

Therefore, one choice to avoid this would be

```
x=zeros(n,1);
for N=1:n-1
    x(N+1)=mod(x(N)+a,1);
end
```

Destroying the potential possibility of making it on **parallel**.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Because `mod(x,y)` is `x-b*y` where `b=floor(x,y)`, so when you try to subtract two big numbers, you will lose a lot (if not all) of significant decimal places and since we are trying to go to [0,1], the numbers you get after a while are completely wrong. 
However, in the last algorithm, you treat small number for each index of the loop, so you will lose at most one significant digit.

Comment: `mod(x,1)=x-floor(x)`. 
Using the first algorithm `x(n) = x(1)+(n-1)*a -floor(x(1)+(n-1)*a)` (Subtraction Of Big Numbers) while in the second  `x(n) = x(n-1) +a - floor(x(n-1)+a)`, where the element `x(n-1)` was already normalized, so there is no subtraction of Big Numbers.

Comment: I think exaza is right. In the second version your calculations rely on a result which already has some (small) error due to calculations.

Comment: Some small error that can be controlled every time is better than a catastrophic cancellation.

In the first case, let us say we have got the number `d = a1a2...as . a(s+1)...a16`. Then `d-floor(d)` will be `0 . a(s+1)...a16`, but if  `s` is big enough, this last number is just wrong due to limited double precision.

In the second case, we lose one digit **at most**, because `d` is always going to have at most `s=1`.

Comment: I just tried your code in MATLAB. I choose *a = pi/4*, and *n = 10e5*. At this point the result with your first code was *x(n) = 0.377999284886755* and with your second code *x(n) = 0.377999284881551*. So both methods will give you very similar results.

Comment: n=10e5 is not big enough. Even worse, if you want to use those numbers to evaluate in a function, lets say `1/sqrt(abs(x-1/2))`, at some point you will get a not negligible number of repetitions that do not exist. Try for instance `n=10^8` and you will see the loss of precision.

Comment: For instance, for `a = (sqrt(5)-1)/2`, `x(1)=0` and `n=10^9`, you will get `x(n) = 0.131860971450806` and  `x(n) = 0.131860913775844`.

Comment: My computer has memory issues with too big arrays (older modell). Might I suggest that you do method one for example with *n = 10e3*, set *x(end)* as your new *x(1)* and repeat this procedure? This way your code will be (almost) parallel and you still won't have big errors.

Comment: It might work for vectorization with relative "small" error, however I don't see how to make it parallel.

Comment: Matlab computes vector operations often parallel.

Comment: My earlier statements were not correct and I have removed them. However, your issue is not the addition and subtraction of big numbers, it's the multiplication of your irrational number by `n` that is causing your loss of precision. e.g. `((sqrt(5)-1)/2)*1e7) = 6180339.887498948700000`

Comment: Which is exactly the point. As long as we manipulate irrational numbers (infinite long sequence of numbers) and we make them big and subtract similar quantities in magnitude, due to the limited precision of the machine, we will get the loss of precision. If we didn't have large numbers, we could have preserved all the significant digits.

Comment: But you're *not* manipulating an irrational number. You're manipulating a `double`, which has a finite precision. If you want arbitrary precision you need to either calculate it yourself, utilize [`vpa`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) (part of MATLAB's Symbolic Math Toolbox), or similar 3rd party toolboxes for MATLAB or another programming language (e.g. Python's [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) or [`gmpy2`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmpy2)).